# Maps on Trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

How can I define a function that operates like map but works on trees? The typesignature of the new funtion would be:

```
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
```

Is it even possible to create a generic typeclass for map?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That typeclass already exists in Prelude: [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor).

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

To implement it, you could use the [`DeriveFunctor`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/DeriveFunctor) language extension so that GHC can implement it for you with just a `deriving` clause:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Functor)

mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree = fmap
```

Or you can implement it manually:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree _ Empty = Empty
mapTree f (Node x l r) = Node (f x) (mapTree f l) (mapTree f r)

instance Functor Tree where
    fmap = mapTree
```